# How to clear all objects in NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

It is okay to add or delete single object in NSManagedObjectContext,just wonder why there is no API to clear all objects one time in NSManagedObjectContext ?

> Specifies an object that should be removed from its persistent store when changes are committed.
>
> - (void)deleteObject:(NSManagedObject *)object

Why there is no API such as clearAllObjects to delete all objects at one time ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes its fine to do so using the deleteObject: method. If you want to delete all objects it might be quicker to destroy your managed object context, delete or change your presistent store and recreate your core data stack

Comment: Specifies an object that should be removed from its persistent store when changes are committed.

- (void)deleteObject:(NSManagedObject *)object

Comment: You can conduct searches for the different entities on the desired context, and then mark them for deletion. Crappy i know, but it's Object persistence framework, not a database abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a simple way to get the results you're looking for with one call. It does require multiple `fetch` and `delete` requests, but you don't need to manually list each entity name.

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    func clearAll() {
        persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectModel.entities.compactMap({ $0.name }).forEach { entity in
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entity)
            try? fetch(fetchRequest).forEach({ delete($0) })
        }
        try? save()
    }
}
```